# Searching for puppet packages website

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I've been looking for a puppet package website such as https://packagist.org/ but with no luck, are there any websites out there where you can search for a mongodb/php or elascticsearch puppet package?

I've looked at puphpet but it doesn't have all the packages that I'm looking for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I am searching for puppet modules, the first place I go to is the official puppetlabs forge:
https://forge.puppetlabs.com/

You can install puppet modules directly from the puppetforge using the following command line:

```
puppet module install puppetlabs-apache --version 0.0.2
```

(http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/modules_installing.html)